# Residue for $L(s,\chi_1)$ not same in Mathematica as theoretical value

Tags: bugs, evaluation, number-theory

I want to find the residue of Dirichlet-L function, defined as $L(s,\chi)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$ for $Re(s)>1$.

We know that $Res_{s=1}L(s,\chi_1)=\frac{\phi(k)}{k}$, where $\chi$ is the principal character $mod$ $k$.

I am using the code `Residue[DirichletL[2, 1, s], {s, 1}]` to find the residue, and the outcome is $0$.

Can anyone explain what is wrong here? Is there some problem in my code or is it with Mathematica?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Also `Series[DirichletL[2, 1, s], {s, 1, 3}]` produces `DirichletL[2,1,1]+(DirichletL^(0,0,1))[2,1,1] (s-1)+1/2 (DirichletL^(0,0,2))[2,1,1] (s-1)^2+1/6 (DirichletL^(0,0,3))[2,1,1] (s-1)^3+O[s-1]^4` though `ComplexPlot3D[DirichletL[2, 1, s], {s, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}]` shows the pole at `s==1`.

Comment: @user64494 So it is something Mathematica is messing up somewhere, and my code is correct?

Comment: I think this is indeed a bug. `DirichletL[2,1,s]` is the same as $(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s)$, and `Residue[(1 - 2^(-s))*Zeta[s], {s, 1}]` produces your desired $1/2$ value, but as you observed, the equivalent `Residue[DirichletL[2, 1, s], {s, 1}]` gives erroneously $0$.